# Why is an exception caught as user-unhandled in the debugger within the scope of Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, exception

I am getting some odd behavior in Visual Studio 2013 when a class that throws an exception from it's constructor is instantiated by `Activator.CreateInstance`. My actual scenario is that I have a MEF component that relies on third party libraries and will throw if those libraries aren't available.

I have reconstructed a simpler repro of it as follows:

Consider the class

```
class FailType
{
    public FailType()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And then the code

```
try
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FailType));
}
catch (Exception)
{ }
```

Ignoring for a moment the obvious pointless nature of the repro code, the Visual Studio debugger will break on the throw of the exception in the `FailType` constructor, and claim that it is user-unhandled - even though it's clearly handled in the context of the calling code.

I was wondering if it had anything to do with the managed to native transition that happens as a part of the internals of `Activator.CreateInstance`. This is on .NET 4.5, for what it's worth.

So, the question is - why is Visual Studio breaking on the exception with an unhandled message, and is there any way to prevent it doing so?

Comment: Don't have VS 2013, but in VS 2012 there's an option under Tools - Options - Debugging - General: Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundries. So if that option is on for you (it's off for me) and if you're right about Activator.CreateInstance involving managed-to-native transition ...

Comment: @RenniePet - Good thought, but that option is off for me too...